# i3 status bar showing impossible(?) CPU usage

Tags: i3

I'm using the i3 window manager on my Ubuntu box.  According to `/proc/cpuinfo`, my machine has 20 processors.  However, when I do a big parallel job (say, `make -j`), i3's status bar will often show a very high CPU usage figure (sometimes over 300).

How is this possible?

Comment: Is that a percentage of one CPU maybe? Or CPU load? It's difficult to say anything precise as you don't mention any units.

Comment: What `i3status` (the thing that normally - and I guess the OP would know if it was different - generates the stuff  shown in i3's status bar is just the load, which is just the number of processes ready to run (technically: in R- or D-state), there's no limit to how high that number can be, and I've seen quite a bit above 300.

Comment: `man i3status` describes it as "the percentual CPU usage".

Comment: @Kusalananda, no units are shown in the status bar.

Comment: @DanielWalker: I can see that in the man page, but that's not in the standard config, that shows load as I described.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity load is not "just the number of processes ready to run", it's considerably more complicated. See [How can I chose a max load threshold depending on the number of available cores?](https://serverfault.com/a/771298).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `i3status`, the thing that normally generates the stuff shown in i3's status bar, is showing is just the load which is just the number of processes ready to run (technically: in R- or D-state).  There's no limit to how high that number can be and I've seen quite a bit above 300.

Comment: You can see which fields are which in `/etc/i3status.conf`.  See [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/i3status.html).

Answer (score 0):

When monitoring CPU usage like this, some software such as mpstat or i3status will consider 1 core's usage to be equal to 100% usage, so in your case, 300% would be equal to 3 cores, or more likely 3 threads depending on the thread count of your CPU.

Comment: I don't think it's a percentage.  According to htop, all 20 processors are at 100%.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps try running a parallel job with a lower job count (like 5) and seeing what happens with i3status?